# Python C++ API make member private

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I'm making a python extension module using my C++ code and I've made a struct that I use to pass my C++ variables. I want some of those variables to be inaccessible from the python level. How can I do that?

```cpp
    typedef struct {
        PyObject_HEAD
        std::string region;
        std::string stream;

        bool m_is_surface = false;
        bool m_is_stream = false;
    } PyType;
```

I want `m_is_surface` and `m_is_stream` to be inaccessible by the user. Only `PyType`'s methods should access it. So the and user **CAN'T** do something like this:

```py
import my_module

instance = my_module.PyType()
instance.m_is_surface = False # This should raise an error. Or preferably the user can't see this at all
```

I cannot just add private to the struct because python type members are created as a standalone function and is linked to the type later on, so I cannot access them inside the struct's methods.
So if I say:

```cpp
 int PyType_init(PyType *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
    {
        static char *kwlist[] = {"thread", "region", "stream", NULL};
        PyObject *tmp;


        if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "bs|s", kwlist,
                                        &self->thread, &self->region, &self->stream))
            return -1;
        
        return 0;
    }
```

It will raise an `is private within this context` error.

Comment: is that not what `private` is for ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If I do that the traditional way then the struct's methods cannot access the members since they are *technically* not a member of the struct. They are bound by the python api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do nothing. Unless you create an accessor property these attributes are *already* inaccessible from Python. Python cannot automatically see C/C++ struct members.

Comment: So if I do not add them to `PyStructMembers` will I still be able to use them regardless?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `PyStructMembers`, but `PyMemberDef`/`PyGetSetDef` are only there to expose things to Python. You can use them in C or C++ fine without